# How to make a custom element post its value during form submit?

Tags: custom-element, x-tag

I'm creating a custom element that wraps a third-party control. For some reason, I have to apply this 3rd-party control on a `<div>` instead on an `<input>` or else it will behave differently.

I'm using x-tag to create the custom element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert a `<input>` tag with attribute `type="hidden"` and then duplicate the content of the `<div>` you want to post, it should work.

As an example, you can read this [other post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40173805/4600982).

Comment: Actually, this is my last resort. Is it not possible for the custom element to be treated as a form element and make its `value` to be captured during post?

Comment: No it not possible by now