# Can I get a button in Shadow DOM to submit a form not in Shadow DOM?

Tags: shadow-dom, custom-element, native-web-component

I just ran into an interesting situation where I have a submit `<button>` inside the Shadow DOM of a native custom element that is placed inside a `<form>`.

```
  <form id="one" action="" method="get">
    <s-button>Select</s-button>
      #shadow-root
        <button>...</button>
    <button>Outside</button>
  </form>
```

I also have a `<button>` as a direct child of the `<form>`.

The child `<button>` causes the form to submit.

But the `<button>` in the shadow-root does not.

In a way I guess this makes sense. But has anyone figured out a way to tell the shadow-root `<button>` to work correctly with the `<form>` or is this something I will have to handle through JS?

I know click events are blocked at the Shadow DOM layer, but I am surprised that there is no way to allow the button to still be a part of the form, something that can be set up through an attribute or a property.

Sure I can capture the click event and then send a new one from `this` but that does not do the same thing since my event will no longer be user generated and there are a huge set of rules associated with that.

Comment: There are more issues with shadowDOM and Forms they are tackling in V2. Do read/follow: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/187

Comment: And (from some years ago) Supersharps answer on copying shadowDOM inputs to the main DOM: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623176/how-can-i-create-a-web-component-that-acts-like-a-form-element

Comment: on click/submit: From [the submit Event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) : "The submit event only fires when the user clicks a submit button [..]  in a form. The event is not raised when calling the form.submit() **method** directly."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to handle it through Javascript anyway.

A simple solution is to add a (masked) `<button>` in the light DOM, and transfer the `click` event to it.

```js
customElements.define( 's-button', class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.attachShadow( {mode: 'open'})
            .innerHTML = `<button>In Shadow</button>`
        var submit = this.appendChild( document.createElement( 'button' ) )
        this.onclick = () => submit.click()
    }
} )
```

```html
<form onsubmit="console.log('submitted');return false">
    <s-button>Select</s-button>
    <button>Outside</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

A button triggers a [submit Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit) (on the FORM element)

Since Events can not pass the shadow DOM boundary (do not bubble up into the parent DOM)

*I presume* that is why a shadowDOM button (dispatching a `submit` event) is not received by the FORM element.

Requires Supersharps workaround with a hidden button in the light DOM  (which then dispatches a `submit` event in the parent DOM)

Or (starting from light DOM) you find the (parent) FORM tag and dispatch a submit event yourself:

`this.closest('FORM').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))`

---

Follow the experts on shadowDOM and FORMs at: https://github.com/w3c/webcomponents/issues/187

---

```js
customElements.define( 'my-button', class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.attachShadow({mode:'open'}).innerHTML=`<button>Button In Shadow DOM</button>`
    this.onclick = _ => this.closest('FORM').dispatchEvent(new Event('submit'))
  }
})
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return console.log('submit Event occured')">
    <my-button></my-button>
    <button>button in Document DOM</button>
</form>
```

#### Nested shadowDOMs

If the FORM is not a direct ancestor, you can find it with something like: [How to reference to a method in parent component from child component with vanilla JS Web Components? (Not any framework or Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481999/how-to-reference-to-a-method-in-parent-component-from-child-component-with-vanil/63483728#63483728)

Answer (score 0):

Something else you can do that is not *exactly* a button in the ShadowDOM, is if your `button[type=submit]` has been slotted into the ShadowDOM. So if you have something like:

```
<some-component>
<button type="submit" slot="buttonSlot"></button>
</some-component>
```

That button can be used to trigger your form.
That button is in the light DOM but is easily handled from within your component via the slot. It will also retain all the appropriate keyboard, click, focus, etc. events without any trouble.

To minimize the light DOM html you don't even need it to be a `type=submit` you can set that from within your component and it will still be treated as the submit button for any parent form in the light DOM.

Bonus (or maybe trouble depending on how you look at it), it will retain the styling of other buttons on the page (unless you change that in your component).