# chrome extension to track file uploads when input elements of webpage are inside shadow dom?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, shadow-dom

Developing chrome extension to track file uploads but few websites have input elements inside the #shadow-root (nested) , so docuement.queryselectors doesn't identify the  elements.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not an easy way out but selecting every possible node in which a shadow dom could be and then select the input elements in it.
If you know first in which nodes you will definitely have a shadow dom, you could tighten the action range using pseudo selector: not ()

```
document.querySelectorAll('body *').forEach(n => {
    if (n.shadowRoot)
        Array.from(n.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('input[type="file"]')).forEach(p => doSomething())
})
```

Comment: This will not find nested elements. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481999/how-to-reference-to-a-method-in-parent-component-from-child-component-with-vanil/63483728#63483728

Comment: It does not find shadom DOM of nested components (and not nested) if they are defined in "closed" mode, otherwise it would find them all.
Bad hassle!

Comment: True, is there a way to track the web uploads by not dependent on page html or javascript constructs using Chrome extension/ native messaging ?