# Access elements in custom component | Vue3 Composition api

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, shadow-dom

I created a custom-component cause I needed to scope the css.

```
import { defineCustomElement } from "vue";
…
const CustomElement = defineCustomElement(ImportConfig);
window.customElements.define("import-new-custom", CustomElement);
```

How would I access elements with JS, to change styles dynamically, inside custom-components using vues composition api?
I tried utilizing template refs but that doesn't fit all needs.

Appreciate all help. Didn't find any up to date information for Vue.

Comment: A custom element is almost the same as any other Vue component - the only difference is that you can directly use it in 3rd party HTML without the need of Vue-template-compiler to preprocess it.

Comment: And still it's using the shadow dom to isolate itself and I can't get elements using 
e.g. `getElementById`.

Comment: If you want to access the DOM nodes inside your Shadow Root - you must use the `open` mode of Shadow DOM. Open vs closed modes are explained in https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af

Comment: If it has an ``open`` shadowRoot, it is ``document.querySelector("import-new-custom").shadowRoot.getElementById(..)``

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thaks! That helped me a lot. Just couldn't figure out how to access the parents shadowRoot. If you could write this as an answer I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an `open` shadowRoot, it is `document.querySelector("import-new-custom").shadowRoot.getElementById(..)`. A `closed` shadowRoot does **not** have a `.shadowRoot` property. But you (the Component Developer) can assign an *entrypoint* yourself.

For a recursive *dive* into shadowRoots; see: [How to reference to a method in parent component from child component with vanilla JS Web Components? (Not any framework or Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481999/how-to-reference-to-a-method-in-parent-component-from-child-component-with-vanil/63483728#63483728)

From *inside* a shadowRoot you get the `host` element with: `this.getRootNode().host`

standard `.closest(...)` does **not** cross shadowRoot boundaries; for a `closestElement(..)` see: [How to reference to a method in parent component from child component with vanilla JS Web Components? (Not any framework or Library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63481999/how-to-reference-to-a-method-in-parent-component-from-child-component-with-vanil/63483728#63483728)